# Java how to split text which is read from sdcard file into different arrays

Tags: java, arrays, android-intent, storage, bundle

I'm doing a school assignment and need some help.

Android
I have these coordinates stored in txt file in my sdcard, They are stored in this way

```
x.xxxxxxxx|x.xxxxxxxxxy
x.xxxxxxxx|x.xxxxxxxxxx
```

and so on.
What I'm doing is trying to use listview.onclicklistener(){, so once I tap on a file, it will read this and send a intent to the map with the data with it. What I want is to store it in a two different array such as Longitude[] and Latitude[] from the same file to send over to the map.class to use as parameters for creating markers. I know how to split it but I have no idea how to store them into individual arrays.

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            File logFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "GPSLogger/testfile.txt");
            InputStream instream = null;
            try {
                instream = new FileInputStream(logFile);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
            String line = null;
            String[] Location = null;
            int i = 0;
            String[] Longitude = null;
            String[] Latitude = null;

            try {
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    Log.v("result" ,result);
                    result += line + "|";

                    Location = result.split("\\|");
                    for (String s : Location) {
                        Log.v("asd",s);
                        i++;
                        if(i%2==0){
                            String[] Longitude = Location[0];

                        }
                        else{
                            String Latitude = Location[0];
                        }
                    }
```

This is what I'm trying but I'm getting quite a few error. Please help and thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post the errors you are getting

Comment: Which lines is it giving you an error?

Answer (score 1):

If file looks like you mentioned in question try this:

```
String longtitudeLine = reader.readLine();
String latitudeLine = reader.readLine();
String[] longtitudeCoordinates = longtitudeLine != null ? longtitudeLine.split("\\|") : null; //Array will be null if line is empty
String[] latitudeCoordinates = latitudeLine != null ? latitudeLine.split("\\|") : null; // Array will be null if line is empty
```

Note: this will work in case you sure that first two lines is coordinates.

Comment: Hold on! I'll give this a try ! Thanks all! Will give all solution a try first.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you MUST instanciate the arrays (especially Latitude and Longitude) before feeding them, but you must know the size of the array before you instanciate them.
And you will only know this size once you've finished reading the line...

It's a dilemna.

Fortunately, there are more than one way to do that.

For example, you can do what you tried : fill all the lines in a (big) string, then fill the arrays.

```
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
        String line = null;
        String[] location = null;
        String longitude = null;
        String latitude = null;
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();


        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.v("result" ,result);
                buffer.append(line).append("|");
            }
        location = buffer.toString().split("\\|");
        // Compute the size of the list
                    // There's an odd number of elements because of the
                    // last trailing '|'
        int size = (location.length - 1) / 2;
        longitude = new String[size];
        latitude = new String[size];
        for (int i=0; i<size;i++) {
            longitude[i]=location[i*2];
            latitude[i]=location[i*2+1];
            }
```

You could also use "dynamic" sized objects, like `ArrayList<String>`, which you can use to store arrays of values when you don't know the lenght in advance...

Comment: By the way : learn how to correctly spell your variables. They should not begin with a capital letter (this is reserved to the Class names). So write `location` instead of `Location`.

Comment: Hello. Thanks! I tried your solution however it only managed to send the first data over meaning Longitude[0] and Latitude[0], and not the rest. Do you have any idea how to fix? If possible do you have skype? So i can ask you better over there.